# Get last replication date/time from SQL server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

I have a Windows Mobile 6.0 application with SQL Server CE 3.5 on the device.  The program gets the latest data from the publisher - SQL Server 2008. The replication is working fine but I want to display to the user the last time it replicated from the server.

Does anyone know where I can get the SQL that I can execute on the device to get this information from the SQL Server CE?

All help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the local Datetime for last succesful synchronization
    /// If no Synchronization has happened, will return DateTime.MinValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">An open connection to the local database</param>
    /// <returns>The date and time for the last succesful sync</returns>
    public DateTime GetLastSuccessfulSyncTime(SqlCeConnection connection)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(connection.Database))
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        var props = GetPropertiesFromSettings();

        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
            cmd.Parameters["@table"].Value = "__sysMergeSubscriptions";
            object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (obj == null)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LastSuccessfulSync FROM __sysMergeSubscriptions " +
                "WHERE Publisher=@publisher AND PublisherDatabase=@database AND Publication=@publication";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@publisher", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
            cmd.Parameters["@publisher"].Value = props.Publisher;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@database", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
            cmd.Parameters["@database"].Value = props.PublisherDatabase;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@publication", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
            cmd.Parameters["@publication"].Value = props.Publication;

            obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (obj == null)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            else
                return ((DateTime)obj);
        }
    }
```